# How do I make this rsync command non-recursive?

Tags: rsync, recursive

```
rsync -avi --delete --modify-window=1 --no-perms --no-o --no-g
    ~/Documents/Stuff/ /media/user/PC/Stuff;;
```

i.e. to not copy sub-directories from the source directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add option `--exclude='*/'` to your rsync options to prevent syncing of directories.

Answer (score 7):

Extract from `man rsync`

```
    -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

`-a`  implies `-r`  so you can :

```
 remove `-a --no-perms --no-o --no-g ` and replace by `-ltD`
```

or

```
 add `--no-recursive`
```

`--delete` add more complexity , from `man rsync`

--delete`

```
Prior to rsync 2.6.7, this option would have no effect unless --recursive was enabled.  
Beginning with 2.6.7, deletions will also occur when --dirs (-d) is  enabled,  but  only  for  directories whose contents are being copied.
```

So you must use `--dirs`